# How is the final result calculated in RK-Dopri(4,5)?

Tags: runge-kutta, education

I have found a toy implementation of [RK-Dopri(4,5)](https://gist.github.com/bzm3r/228a7935df306e86a92ac261fdad8e30), written in Python.

I am concerned however, about [line 118](https://gist.github.com/bzm3r/228a7935df306e86a92ac261fdad8e30#file-ode45-py-L118):

```
y = y + h * (b1*K1+b3*K3+b4*K4+b5*K5+b6*K6)
```

Has the term `b2*K2` been omitted on purpose? I have a feeling that it is not, given (1.8) in Hairer, Wanner and Norsett:

[image]

Can you confirm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$b_2$ is zero in the [Butcher tableau for Dormand-Prince](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dormand%E2%80%93Prince_method), so you can skip that term.

Note that also the code you linked to contains lines `b2 = 0.0`, `b2p = 0.0`, which are just there as a reminder because those variables are never used.